# Change windows hostname from command line

Tags: windows, command-line

Is it possible to change the hostname in Windows 2003 from the command line with out-of-the-box tools?

Comment: 175K views... Active 5 months ago... Asked 12 Years ago and closed 2 Years ago. Can't we just let useful posts live? This question may not be great, but it is on topic.

Comment: @dmo This script can be interesting : https://gist.github.com/timnew/2373475

Comment: When this question was asked in 2008, you indeed needed the `wmic` or `netdom` commands given in the answers. Nowadays, in PowerShell, you can do `Rename-Computer "NewName" -Restart`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The netdom.exe command line program can be used.  This is available from the Windows XP Support Tools or Server 2003 Support Tools (both on the installation CD).

Usage guidelines [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170928171940/https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/298593/how-to-use-the-netdom-exe-utility-to-rename-a-computer-in-windows-xp)

Comment: It would be better if you described how to use it (as in [@litao's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20087946/1098603)), as the link you provided is now dead.

Comment: FYI, 11 years later and link is dead. This is why adding examples is useful

Comment: The guideline are still available [here](https://www.betaarchive.com/wiki/index.php/Microsoft_KB_Archive/298593).

Answer (score 54):

The previously mentioned `wmic` command is the way to go, as it is installed by default in recent versions of Windows.

Here is my small improvement to generalize it, by retrieving the current name from the environment:

```dos
wmic computersystem where name="%COMPUTERNAME%" 
     call rename name="NEW-NAME"
```

NOTE: The command must be given in one line, but I've broken it into two to make scrolling unnecessary.  As @rbeede mentions you'll have to reboot to complete the update.

Comment: You have to reboot after executing

Comment: I think `wmic` is not delivered with Windows XP

Comment: A bit shorter: `wmic computersystem where name="%COMPUTERNAME%" rename "NEW-NAME"`

Answer (score 14):

cmd (command):

```dos
netdom renamecomputer %COMPUTERNAME% /Newname "NEW-NAME"
```

powershell (windows 2008/2012):

```sh
netdom renamecomputer "$env:COMPUTERNAME" /Newname "NEW-NAME"
```

after that, you need to reboot your computer.

Comment: Nope, not on Win8 at least. netdom not recognized.

Comment: works fine in win 2016 core

Comment: Didn't work on Win 10, but did work for me on Win 2016 Server.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a command to do this, but you could do it in VBScript or something similar.
Somthing like:

```vb
sNewName = "put new name here" 

Set oShell = CreateObject ("WSCript.shell" ) 

sCCS = "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\" 
sTcpipParamsRegPath = sCCS & "Services\Tcpip\Parameters\" 
sCompNameRegPath = sCCS & "Control\ComputerName\" 

With oShell 
.RegDelete sTcpipParamsRegPath & "Hostname" 
.RegDelete sTcpipParamsRegPath & "NV Hostname" 

.RegWrite sCompNameRegPath & "ComputerName\ComputerName", sNewName 
.RegWrite sCompNameRegPath & "ActiveComputerName\ComputerName", sNewName 
.RegWrite sTcpipParamsRegPath & "Hostname", sNewName 
.RegWrite sTcpipParamsRegPath & "NV Hostname", sNewName 
End With ' oShell 

MsgBox "Computer name changed, please reboot your computer"
```

[Original](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/26545-45-change-computer-name-command-line-registry)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way of doing it with a WHS script:

```vb
Set objWMIService = GetObject("Winmgmts:root\cimv2")

For Each objComputer in _
    objWMIService.InstancesOf("Win32_ComputerSystem")

    objComputer.rename "NewComputerName", NULL, NULL 
Next
```

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393056(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Use below command to change computer hostname remotely , Require system reboot after change..

`psexec.exe -h -e \\\IPADDRESS -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD netdom renamecomputer CurrentComputerName /newname:NewComputerName /force`

Answer (score 1):

Why be easy when it can be complicated?
Why use third-party applications like netdom.exe when correct interogations is the way?
Try 2 interogations:

**wmic computersystem where caption='%computername%' get caption, UserName, Domain /format:value**

**wmic computersystem where "caption like '%%%computername%%%'" get caption, UserName, Domain /format:value**

or in a batch file use loop

**for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%i in ('wmic computersystem where "Caption like '%%%currentname%%%'" get UserName /format:value') do (echo. UserName- %%i)**

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to do this from Windows 10 IoT, then there is a built in command you can use:

`setcomputername [newname]`

Unfortunately, this command does *not exist* in the full build of Windows 10.